# Add instruction at the end of transaction in rust

Tags: solana-program, rust, solana-sdk, jupiter

working on adding a tx to a Versionned Transaction do you know how i should proceed using rust

```
// return <jupiter>/swap

let mut versioned_transaction: VersionedTransaction = bincode::deserialize(&swap_response.swap_transaction).unwrap();
versioned_transaction.message.set_recent_blockhash(Hash::from_str(&latest_blockhash).unwrap());
let private_key = env::var("SOL_PRIVATE_KEY").unwrap_or_default();
let wallet = initialize_wallet(private_key);
let signed_versioned_transaction = VersionedTransaction::try_new(versioned_transaction.message, &[&wallet]).unwrap();

let transfer_instruction = system_instruction::transfer(//sender pubkey, &receiver pubkey, lamports_to_transfer); // <- transfer to add at the end of transaction

// rest of the program, sending transac
```

any starting point would be nice